# resourcebundle vs properties

Tags: java, resourcebundle

Hi I have a problem loading Properties to Java.

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale);
```

Loads a file from main source folder.

while

```
InputStream in = ThisClass.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName);
properties.load(in);
```

loads a file from main project folder, which is outside classpath. 
For now it is unclear how to load properties from source folder as well.

I don't want propertiesFileName to have `/src/` in it because it won't work from jar then.
Could it be relater to my IDE, I use Netbeans.

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` should load from the class path.

Comment: ResourceBundle has nothing to do with the main source folder. They both load from the CLASSPATH, and these two invocations should both do the same thing. What's the question?

Comment: Yes this is the question, but or some weird reason it does not work as it should.

Comment: Which one doesn't work? Doesn't work how? How are you expecting it to work?

Comment: Second will not work with `/src/` in front of the reource name (unless you have a java package named `src`). Where did you use `src` and saw that is works? How are you sure that second loads from project folder?

Comment: In both cases you are better off having the properties/resources files in the classpath.

Comment: second case reads file from one level up in classpath, May be it is related to IDE. Testing now.

Comment: @EJP: they don't do exactly the same thing. First approach interprets the given resource path relative to root location in the classpath and second approach interprets the given resource path relative to location of `ThisClass` in the classpath. OP'd better use the context class loader instead (and get the concept "classpath" straight; this is definitely not "outside" classpath).

Comment: You can never load something from the src folder. It is not available at run-time. Make sure the file you are trying to load is on the class path (**Hint:** If your SOURCE path is on the CLASS path, you are doing something wrong).

Comment: @BalusC it worked. Do You want to put it as an answer? 
to MikkelLøkke - I ment output directory as src, because while compile netbeans puts all those properties files into.

Comment: @Balusc You missed the class.getClass() in the source code. They do the same thing. Or rather perhaps the second one looks for /java/lang/<properties filename> ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem recently!

try:

```
        InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName);
    properties.load(in);
```